# MySQL - List conversations

Tags: mysql

Like we've in popular messaging systems.

I want to display list of conversations current user has with other users, conversations containing both sent and received messages, displaying only the latest message of each conversation, and latest conversations at top.

In my following SQL statement:
Binary field `read` = 1 means the receiver has read the message. If the current user didn't read some message he received then whole of that conversation is shown as unread to the current user. But the current user shouldn't know whether the other person has read message sent by the current user. Binary field `delto` = 1 means the receiver deleted the message, the sender would still have the message; similarly for `delfrom`. Joining with users table to get users' names.

Suppose the current user's id is 2. I want something like this:

> select `userid`, `name`, latest-message-of-conversation, timestamp-of-latest-message-of-conversation, bit_and(if(`to`=2,`read`,b'1')) as `read` from `messages` join `users` on (`to`=2 and `delto`=b'0' and `from`=`userid`) or (`from`=2 and `delfrom`=b'0' and `to`=`userid`) group by `userid` order by max(`messid`) desc

Relevant fields, but you can ignore:

```
create table `users`(
`userid` mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`name` tinytext not null
);

create table `messages`(
`messid` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
`from` mediumint unsigned not null,
`to` mediumint unsigned not null,
`message` text not null,
`time` datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`read` bit(1) not null default b'0',
`delfrom` bit(1) not null default b'0',
`delto` bit(1) not null default b'0'
);
```

Comment: Sooo... what is the problem with the "something like this" code you posted?

Comment: @IanKemp How to implement/get "latest-message-of-conversation" in that code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Since i was having trouble aggregating `message` and `time` so i took them outside of the select query. Well, `time` could have been aggregated as max(`time`) but why do it when max(`messid`) was already aggregating the messages. So here's a solution i found:

> select `userid`, `name`, `message`, `time`, `conversations`.`read` from (select max(`messid`) as `mmid`, `userid`, `name`, bit_and(if(`to`=2,`read`,b'1')) as `read` from `messages` join `users` on (`to`=2 and `delto`=b'0' and `from`=`userid`) or (`from`=2 and `delfrom`=b'0' and `to`=`userid`) group by `userid` order by `mmid` desc) as `conversations` join `messages` on `messid`=`mmid`